# Using SQL in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, web

i'm following w3schools.com to learn php and html and when i paste this code my app doesnt work with this error.
code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","");
$sql="CREATE DATABASE my_db";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  echo "Database my_db created successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
  }
```

error:
Error creating database: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'my_db'

Comment: Read manual: http://se1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: How did you setup your server?

Comment: @Salman using wamp server

Comment: Also w3schools is a notoriously poor source for coding samples. You should utilize the PHP.net documentation.

Comment: Make sure you have the proper permissions/privileges set to "create" DB's and you could also try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` or `127.0.0.1:80` or SQL's default port `3306`

Comment: sorry i'm not a expert how can i change's SQL defualt port @Fred-ii-

Comment: I think you created a new user called *admin*, and didn't give it permission to *create* databases.

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1:3306` see if that helps.

Comment: most important thing: http://w3fools.com

Answer (score 0):

After you create the db, grant all permission to your user admin like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON my_db.* TO admin@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "PASSWORD";
```